# Typescript generic useAsync with Axios infers 'unknown' instead of correct response type

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, axios, typescript-generics

I have created a generic useAsync hook using axios.
At the moment, for some reason I can't work out, the response is inferred as `unknown` instead of `AxiosResponse<MyOwnType>`

I have a working [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-dewdney-7sr3jd) which illustrates the issue.
`data` is typed as `unknown`  which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do here isn't really possible with TypeScript:

```
// Can't define a second generic by a `unknown` generic type
const useAsync = <D, F extends PromiseFn<D>>(promiseFn: F) => {
```

1- So, what you should do instead, is to remove the `D` generic from the function's signature.

2- The second part, is moving the `asyncReducer` function inside of your own hook and leverage the already defined `F` generic.

```
const useAsync = <F extends PromiseFn<any>>(promiseFn: F) => {

  const asyncReducer = (
    state: AsyncState<AxiosResponseType<F>>,
    action: AsyncAction<AxiosResponseType<F>>
  ): AsyncState<AxiosResponseType<F>> => {
...
```

3- You can now remove the type assertion you have on line 68 and pass in the generic's return type by defining the following type:

```
type AxiosResponseType<F extends PromiseFn<any>> = Awaited<ReturnType<F>>;
```

4- Use this new generic to type `state`, `action` and the return type of the reducer, and you should be good to go!

[Link with working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-https-iebcr0?file=/src/useAsync.ts:706-780)

Comment: Thanks Pedro... 'vote for Pedro' 